# ORMLite / ServiceStack soft deletes

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Okay, I've posted a couple of times regarding this, and still have yet to come to a working solution here.  I've seen other examples / suggestions and followed them, and am having no success.  I'm at the end of my rope and hope to gain clarity here.  Ultimately, I'm trying to implement the ability to select any object in the database, while filtering on the 'IsDeleted' flag.

I'm using ORMLite with ServiceStack.  I'm using the repository pattern, and also using Funq with ServiceStack.  When my AppHost starts, I register my DbConnectionFactory in the container, as well as my repository instances as well.  The connection factory is passed through constructor injection.

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    <...>

    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
    container.Register<ICompanyRepository>(c => new Repositories.OrmLite.CompanyRepository(container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

    <...>
}
```

All of my model classes have a common base class / interface that contains our standard audit fields, as well as the 'IsDeleted' flag.  This is represented by an interface named 'IAuditModel':

```
public interface IAuditModel
{
    int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    bool IsModified { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository class, I'm attempting to retrieve records that are not marked as deleted, but I'm trying to avoid having to specify this on every query.  I've attempted this by creating a specific select filter for the type in the constructor of the base repository class:

```
public class OrmLiteRepositoryBase : IRepositoryBase
{
    <...>

    protected readonly OrmLiteConnectionFactory olcf;

    public OrmLiteRepositoryBase(IDbConnectionFactory cf)
    {
        olcf = cf as OrmLiteConnectionFactory;

        SqlExpression<Vendor>.SelectFilter = q => q.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);

        OrmLiteConfig.InsertFilter = (dbCmd, row) =>
        {
            <...>
        }

        OrmLiteConfig.UpdateFilter = (dbCmd, row) =>
        {
            <...>
        }

        <...>
    }
}
```

The Vendor class implements IAuditModel through a base class.  The above was my first attempt at filtering on specific types.  I then tried the below, following suggestions I found on stackoverflow here, as well as in the [SoftDeleteUseCase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Tests/UseCase/SoftDeleteUseCase.cs) on github:

```
OrmLiteConfig.SqlExpressionSelectFilter = (q) =>
{
    if(q.ModelDef.ModelType.HasInterface(typeof(IAuditModel))
    {
        a.Where<IAuditModel>(x => x.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

I've tried including this select filter in the following:

1. In the app host, after registering the connection factory.
2. In the repository constructor, where the InsertFilter is located.
3. In the repository method itself, after opening the DbConnection.

I'm ultimately making the query in a shared base class with a generic method as follows:

```
db.Select<T>();
```

Nothing works, I get all records back (including ones marked as 'deleted') every time.  Interesting that the InsertFilter and UpdateFilter as shown above in the repository constructor work as I would expect.  I cannot for the life of me get this select filter to work.  Calling 'GetLastSql()' after the 'Select()' call is made shows no sign of the filter being applied.  Someone, anyone, please help me make some sense of this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Soft deletes filter appends condition to an `SqlExpression` and therefore [only applies to APIs that use an SqlExpression](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#soft-deletes) in its implementation, e.g:

```
var results = db.Select(db.From<Table>());
var result = db.Single(db.From<Table>().Where(x => x.Name == "foo"));
var result = db.Single(x => x.Name == "foo");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, mythz - there are times where I can't imagine not using ServiceStack.  this is one of those times where I feel like I banged my head against the wall for far too long on this issue.  I am updating my question to include how I was actually calling this query.  changing my approach from:

db.Select<T>();

to:

db.Select(db.From<Table>());

indeed makes it work.  it seems like such a minor difference though, from a calling perspective.  I can see that the generated SQL includes the filter, but what is the reasoning for not allowing the first approach the same?

Comment: @StratMN as per my answer it's because the SqlExpression filters only apply to APIs that use an `SqlExpression<T>` which `db.Select<T>()` does not.